# Visual Studio 2019 installer runs after extracting but closes after a few seconds

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2019, windows-7-x64

I have the vs_community__1463967417.1589547493.exe when I run it, I see it extracting and requests me to give admin permissions, I allow, and nothing happens but it just creates files in the Temp folder.

Contents of the Temp folder:

```
VSFaultInfo
dd_bootstrapper_20200818220314.txt
dd_vs_community__1463967417.1589547493_decompression_log.txt
```

The VSFaultInfo is a folder by the way.

Content of the dd_bootstrapper_20200818220314.txt:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 8/18/2020 10:03:14 PM
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Commandline arguments = --env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\b1\Downloads\vs_community__1463967417.1589547493.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\b1\Downloads
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Parent process name = vs_community__1463967417.1589547493
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Parent process product version = 16.8.30404.54
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: CampaignId = 1463967417.1589547493
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: ResponseId not available in 'vs_setup_bootstrapper.config'. Trying to parse filename.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: loading config settings: -update --update --layout -offline --offline --locale --layout --originalworkingdir --installLayoutPath --env
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Caught Exception: Type = XamlParseException, Message = Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Border.BorderBrush' threw an exception., StackTrace =    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.View.Root..ctor(RootViewModel viewModel)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.InteractiveViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.InteractiveViewModel..ctor(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.ViewModelFactory.Create(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper..ctor(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)
InnerException:Type = BadImageFormatException, Message = An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B), StackTrace =    at MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.SafeNativeMethodsPrivate.GetProcessDpiAwareness(HandleRef hProcess, IntPtr& awareness)
   at MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.GetProcessDpiAwareness(HandleRef hProcess)
   at MS.Internal.DpiUtil.ProcessDpiAwarenessHelper.GetProcessDpiAwarenessFromWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
   at MS.Internal.DpiUtil.ProcessDpiAwarenessHelper.GetProcessDpiAwareness(IntPtr hWnd)
   at MS.Internal.DpiUtil.GetProcessDpiAwarenessContextValue(IntPtr hWnd)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.get_ProcessDpiAwarenessContextValue()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)
   at System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression.GetRawValue(DependencyObject d, Object& source, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression.GetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateExpression(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Expression expr, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: General Failure. Message:Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Border.BorderBrush' threw an exception. Callstack:    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.View.Root..ctor(RootViewModel viewModel)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.InteractiveViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.InteractiveViewModel..ctor(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.ViewModelFactory.Create(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper..ctor(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args) Inner Message:An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) Internal Exception:    at MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.SafeNativeMethodsPrivate.GetProcessDpiAwareness(HandleRef hProcess, IntPtr& awareness)
   at MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.GetProcessDpiAwareness(HandleRef hProcess)
   at MS.Internal.DpiUtil.ProcessDpiAwarenessHelper.GetProcessDpiAwarenessFromWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
   at MS.Internal.DpiUtil.ProcessDpiAwarenessHelper.GetProcessDpiAwareness(IntPtr hWnd)
   at MS.Internal.DpiUtil.GetProcessDpiAwarenessContextValue(IntPtr hWnd)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.get_ProcessDpiAwarenessContextValue()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)
   at System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression.GetRawValue(DependencyObject d, Object& source, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression.GetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateExpression(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Expression expr, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: Sending Watson Bucket with:
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P1  = vs_setup_bootstrapper
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P2  = 2.8.27.31978
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P3  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P4  = Install
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P5  = https://aka.ms/vs/16/pre/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P6  = n/a
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P7  = 5002
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P8  = -2146233087
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P9  = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: P10 = VisualStudio.16.Preview
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: Including dmp file
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:8/18/2020 10:03:15 PM: Watson: Including Log : C:\Users\b1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_bootstrapper_20200818220314.log
```

Content of the dd_vs_community__1463967417.1589547493_decompression_log.txt:

```
[8/18/2020, 22:3:13] === Logging started: 2020/08/18 22:03:13 ===
[8/18/2020, 22:3:13] Executable: C:\Users\b1\Downloads\vs_community__1463967417.1589547493.exe v16.8.30404.54
[8/18/2020, 22:3:13] --- logging level: standard ---
[8/18/2020, 22:3:13] Directory 'C:\Users\b1\AppData\Local\Temp\a37c51ba21fd2bc0bdda488a\' has been selected for file extraction
[8/18/2020, 22:3:13] Extracting files to: C:\Users\b1\AppData\Local\Temp\a37c51ba21fd2bc0bdda488a\
[8/18/2020, 22:3:14] Extraction took 312 milliseconds
[8/18/2020, 22:3:14] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\b1\Downloads\vs_community__1463967417.1589547493.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\b1\Downloads"'
[8/18/2020, 22:3:16] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[8/18/2020, 22:3:16] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x138a
[8/18/2020, 22:3:16] === Logging stopped: 2020/08/18 22:03:16 ===
```

Content of the VSFaultInfo folder:

```
200818_100315_3788281
```

Content of the 200818_100315_3788281 folder:

```
ErrorInformation.txt
```

Content of ErrorInformation.txt:

```
Error Information
AppInsightsEvent Name = vs/setup/bootstrapper/error
          Description = XamlParseException
     TelemetrySession = 'fcc8a893-b427-4652-abc5-058d5c71de30' Started = True OptIn=True IsInitialized = False Cloned = False
      WatsonEventType = VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2
             UTC time = 2020-08-18T14:03:15

 Exception:
 System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
 Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Border.BorderBrush' threw an exception.
 System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
 System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
 System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
 System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.View.Root..ctor(RootViewModel viewModel)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.InteractiveViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<.ctor>b__0()
 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.InteractiveViewModel..ctor(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.ViewModelFactory.Create(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper..ctor(IServiceContainer serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)

     Inner Exception:
     System.BadImageFormatException
     An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
     MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.SafeNativeMethodsPrivate.GetProcessDpiAwareness(HandleRef hProcess, IntPtr& awareness)
     MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.GetProcessDpiAwareness(HandleRef hProcess)
     MS.Internal.DpiUtil.ProcessDpiAwarenessHelper.GetProcessDpiAwarenessFromWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
     MS.Internal.DpiUtil.ProcessDpiAwarenessHelper.GetProcessDpiAwareness(IntPtr hWnd)
     MS.Internal.DpiUtil.GetProcessDpiAwarenessContextValue(IntPtr hWnd)
     System.Windows.SystemResources.get_ProcessDpiAwarenessContextValue()
     System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener()
     System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
     System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)
     System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression.GetRawValue(DependencyObject d, Object& source, DependencyProperty dp)
     System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression.GetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
     System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateExpression(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Expression expr, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry)
     System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
     System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
     MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
WerReportAddDump PID=1556 vs_setup_bootstrapper WerDumpTypeMiniDump
```

Can anyone help me? I've checked quite a lot of questions related to this but nothing worked.

PS: I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium x64 SP1. And I am very sure VS 2019 supports Win 7. I have used it all the time on this OS. I have already checked the
[minimum system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements).

Extra Info—My system:
[System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjwlW.png)

Comment: Windows 7 is end of life, so not likely "supported" any more.

Comment: It was working on my other windows 7 x64 SP1 laptop which is running on Intel Pentium.
But this one is Intel Core i5.

Comment: System.BadImageFormatException measn you mixed some DLLs in with different CPU architectures. Run [sfc or DISM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness) to detect corruptions.

Comment: But the [sfc or DISM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness) is for **Enterprise**. I'm on Win7 **Home Premium**. There's another link that leads to [Fix Windows Update Errors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors), but it's for windows 10.

Comment: sfc/DISM can be used on an SKUs, not only Enterprise

Comment: What do you mean by SKU?

Comment: SKU = Windows Edition (Home/Pro/Enterprise)

Comment: I have tried [sfc or DISM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness "sfc or DISM") but it still didn't work.

Comment: you try the 16.8 preview installer, try the installer from stable branch (16.7)

Comment: ok.............

Comment: does 16.7 installer work?

Comment: no.............

Comment: Can anyone help?